# How to stop holding down a button in python console

Tags: python, keyboard

I'm making a console clicker game on replit and came across a bit of a hiccup. I'm trying to make it so you can't just hold down the enter key and make tons of money. Some things that I thought about but couldn't get on my own were: making it so it only registers when your key is released instead of on keypress. The other was putting a limit on the number of clips per minute. Here is an example of what I'm making for reference.

```
def start():
  while True:
    print("You have $%s"%money)
    input("Press enter for money")
    money += 1
start()
```

Once again, this is a very simple version. But if you have any ideas I'd be grateful for the help!
Thanks!

Comment: Look at the `keyboard` module, maybe?  BTW you don't want to do this via recursion, your program will crash after a few thousand iterations.  Use a `while` loop instead.

Comment: Thanks, I'll put more thought into it. Don't worry, like I said this is super simplified it's that way in my real program.

Comment: Hey, @theflyingpig131? Just as a heads up, when posting code, don't add a simplified version of the code, copy the code (the important parts at least), and then paste that. Also: are you trying to make a text game, or are you using Pygame/Pygame Zero?